# CRTP intermediate class that needs to also be made final

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have an inheritance chain of CRTP classes. The CRTP classes derive from each other, until a 'final' derived class passes itself as the CRTP parameter and finalizes the inheritance chain.

```
template <class W>
struct Base
{
    .....
};
template <class W>
struct Derived_inheritable: public Base<W>
{
....
}

template <class W>
struct Derived2_inheritable: public Derived_inheritable<W>
{
....
}

...
```

What I want to do is to be able to have such 'final' end-user classes at each level of the CRTP inheritance chain, that involve no templates:

```
typedef Derived1_inheritable<Derived1> Derived1;
```

As you can guess, this typedef does not work, because it references its own type being defined. The question is how to achieve this?
The way I could think of, is:

```
struct Derived1: public Derived1_inheritable<Derived1>
{
   //not convenient, need to redefine at least a forwarding constructor
}
```

As the comment in the code says, this is not a very elegant solution  - I need to redefine the constructor to forward to the base constructor. Does anyone know a more elegant way?

Comment: I can't say your examples were illuminating, and the phrasing of the question, an *intermediate* class that is *final*, is self-contradictory. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Intermediate here means that I have  CRTP classes that derive from each other, until a final derived class passes itself as the CRTP parameter and finalizes the inheritance chain. What I want to do is th be able to have such 'final' classes at each level of the CRTP inheritance chain

Answer (score 1):

<strike>typedef Derived1_inheritable Derived1;</strike>

That line makes no sense, the argument to the template is a *type* but you are trying to pass a *template* (incidentally the same template that you are instantiating, but besides that extra quirk the fact is that your template takes a *type* as argument and you are passing a non-type)

It is not really clear from the question what you are trying to achieve. You should work on stating your *goal* rather than your *approach* to solving that goal.

> I want to make a "final" class for each DerivedX_inheritable that is non-template and passes itself as the W parameter.

That is exactly done in the code that you produded:

```
struct Derived1: public Derived1_inheritable<Derived1> {}
```

which is a type definition (*make a "final" class*). The fact that your CRTP bases require arguments that must be provided by the end user and the need of the forwarding constructor thereof is just a side effect of your design.

Comment: Well, I thought the best way to illustrate it is to write the code that shows the class hierarchy. I guess the typedef line is what is confusing here, so I have clarified it in the comment to the first answer.

Comment: Yes, it's a side effect, and I am looking for a way to compensate for it, by defining end-user classes at each level, that involve no templates. I am looking for an alternative solution to the one I have found, because I don't want to create (hence the typedef, if it were possible) additional classes (and constructors)

Comment: @AlexanderVassilev: Whether you like it or not, that is what your design leads to. There's nothing you can do there. You could try writing a macro that will take some of the boiler plate, but you *need* to define a new type, and that type must have a constructor

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. There is no other way I can achieve the benefits of this design, so this inconvenience is quite small compared to the benefits. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an elegant solution:

```
template <class W>
struct Base
{
   .....
};
template <class W>
struct Derived_inheritable: public Base<W>
{
....
}

//solution
struct Derived2_dummy;

template <class W=derived2d_ummy>
struct Derived2_inheritable: public Derived_inheritable<W>
{
....
}
struct derived2_dummy: public: Derived_inheritable<>{};
typedef Derived2_inheritable<> Derived2;
```